# AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory") always returns Null

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, datadirectory

In my program, I need to copy a template database from the default location, which I understand will be different depending on the installer I choose to use. The problem is that I can't seem to read the actual path of |DataDirectory| I understand that I should use AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory") but it always returns Null in debugger which means I can't test my code. I've tried the following two syntaxes:

```
string sourcePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory").ToString();
```

and

```
string defaultpath = Convert.ToString(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory"));
```

Am I doing something wrong?

ThanX!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try with APPBASE

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("APPBASE")
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomainsetup.applicationbase.aspx

If you want `DataDirectory` key you must execute before `SetData`

Comment: Thank you. Just to confirm, as I understand it the database could be stored in different locations based on how it's packaged. I understand debug puts it in the app folder, but that if it's deployed as with ClickOnce the database could be in a sub-folder and that MSI does something else completely.

Comment: What does this have to do with |DataDirectory| ?

Comment: For me, that's null too.